# How to make the local orientation to match the global orientation?

Tags: transform-orientation

My local orientation looks like this: 
[image]

My globals like this:
[image]
I know I could rotate them but I have to do it for multiple objects so I was wondering if there's a shortcut

Comment: If you want to keep your objects rotated as they are, you can select all visible objects by pressing A or just select the object you want manually, then press Ctrl+A and select rotation.

Comment: yes of course i'm stupid

Comment: @moonboots your now deleted solution was what I was looking for!

Comment: well, for the global orientation, Ctrl A is the fastest of course  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ⇾ **Apply Rotation**

Noted, that has been already answered in comments, so mark them as wiki